# How to create counter loops inside of boolean method and call in main method

Tags: java, boolean, counter

I have to add a counter to my program to count total number of groups processed, valid groups and invalid groups. Also, if one of the numbers processed is invalid >300 or <0, the program main should skip processing the rest of the scores and go to the nest group. I added a while loop with a sentinel of -1 to create iterations. Its looping now, but the counter isn't working how i'd like. and im still not sure how to count invalid groups and valid groups

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class BowlingProgram {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    //instantiate objects
    //PrintWriter outputFile= new PrintWriter(System.out);
    File myFile=new File ("bowlingScores.txt");

    int score1, score2, score3, notValid=0, valid=0, count=0;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);


        while(count!=-1) {
    System.out.print("Please enter score 1 (enter -1 to STOP): ");
    score1 = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Please enter score 2 (enter -1 to STOP): ");
    score2 = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Please enter score 3 (enter -1 to STOP): ");
    score3 = scanner.nextInt();
     count++;

    validGroup(score1, score2, score3, myFile);

    oneGameScore(score1,myFile);
    oneGameScore(score2,myFile);
    oneGameScore(score3,myFile);

    /*while(validGroup(score1,score2,score3,myFile)!=true) {
        notValid++;
    }
    System.out.println("we have processed"+notValid+"invalid scores");
    while(validGroup(score1,score2,score3,myFile)==true) {
        valid++;
    }
    System.out.println("we have processed"+valid+"invalid scores");
    */
System.out.println("The average score is " + avg3Scores(score1,score2, score3));
oneGameScore(avg3Scores(score1,score2,score3), myFile);
System.out.println();
System.out.println();
System.out.println();
    }

System.out.println("You have processed "+count+"    groups.");
public static boolean validGroup(int score1, int score2, int score3, File myFile)
{
    if(score1 >300) {
        System.out.println("The number you entered for score1 is greater than 300");
        return false;
    }

    if(score1 <0) {
        System.out.println("The number you entered for score1 is less than 0");
        return false;
    }
    if(score2 >300) {
        System.out.println("The number you entered for score2 is greater than 300");
        return false;
    }

    if(score2 <0) {
        System.out.println("The number you entered for score2 is less than 0");
        return false;
    }
    if(score3 >300) {
        System.out.println("The number you entered for score3 is greater than 300");
        return false;
    }

    if(score3 <0) {
        System.out.println("The number you entered for score3 is less than 0");
        return false;
    }
    System.out.println("This group is valid");
     return true;



}
public static void oneGameScore(int score, File myfile) {

    if(score <=300 && score >=250)
        System.out.println("You've played a proffesional game!");
    if(score <=249 && score >=200)
        System.out.println("You've played an excellent game!");
    if(score <=199 && score >=150)
        System.out.println("You've played a very good game!");
    if(score <=149 && score >=100)
        System.out.println("You've played a good game!");
    if(score <=99 && score >=50)
        System.out.println("You've played a poor game!");
    if(score <=49)
        System.out.println("You've played a horrible game");
}

public static int avg3Scores(int sc_1, int sc_2,int sc_3)
{
int avg= (sc_1+sc_2+sc_3)/3;
return avg;

    }

  }
```

Comment: Your program is currently validating only one group every time it's launched. There's nothing to count.

Comment: `if one of the numbers processed is invalid >300 or <0, the program main should skip processing the rest of the scores and go to the nest group` this means it should ask input again?

Comment: while(count!=-1) {
  System.out.print("Please enter score 1 (enter -1 to STOP): ");
  score1 = scanner.nextInt();
  System.out.print("Please enter score 2 (enter -1 to STOP): ");
  score2 = scanner.nextInt();
  System.out.print("Please enter score 3 (enter -1 to STOP): ");
  score3 = scanner.nextInt();
  
  
  count++;
  scanner.close();
  
I've added this while loop to the code but once it tries to iterate a second time i receive an errorPlease enter score 1 (enter -1 to STOP): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Scanner closed

Comment: oh i closed the scanner too early.

Comment: what is this update code in post not in comments @CCMont